# How to switch from bitmap drawables to vector drawables with SVG resources?

Tags: android, android-support-library, vector-graphics

I am currently using a few versions of PNG images in different resolutions.

With new [support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) (23.2) released it should be now possible to use vector graphics on older devices. I've read the blog and watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlFVIIstKmA), so I understand changes I need to make in gradle build configuration file, but I dont see how to switch from PNG to SVG. How do I make a VectorDrawable from SVG and do I have to make a changes to the code?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. All the information you need, is in the blog post you linked. You just need to remove the PNGs, add the SVGs, follow the steps from the blog post, and you're done.

Comment: Only thing I see there is some changes in gradle build config files. Where do you see to add SVG files? Most importantly to where to add them? Now, that there will be just one version instead of all those ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi...

Comment: You need to create the SVGs yourself and simply add them to your drawables.
Technically speaking, you can put them in any drawable directory you like, and it will work. It might be nice to keep them in the no-dpi directory now (assuming that'll work now). Check out this blog post: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/12/21/nodpi-anydpi-wtf.html

Comment: Well I already ahve svg from designer. And we need to generate 4 versions out of them. That is what I want to avoid by using svg directly. But I had the feeling I have to convert svg to something else that android will understand. Did I missunderstood?

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes. Right-click your res folder, select New -> Vector Asset, and then select an svg from disk. Then Android Studio will convert it for you.

Comment: That's what I needed. However in Androud Studio 1.5.1 its buggy and do not want to let me add new asset (I need to pick smaller image to enable 'Next' button and then choose whatever SVG I want). Thank you. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193832